# Opening Wizard: Selected wizard could not be started

Tags: eclipse, haskell

I've got an error while trying to start Haskell project in Eclipse.

Here are error details:

```
The selected wizard could not be started.

Plug-in net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui was unable to load class net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui.wizards.NewHaskellProjectWizard.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui (504).
```

Any ideas what can i do to fix it?